# Burning a CD keeping original timestamps for files

Tags: burning, brasero

Is it possible to do what is summarized in the title? I would really like the files on my disc and ISO images to be marked with same creation date and modification date as in original files.

I mostly use *Brasero*; anyway also a solution with different program would be OK, as soon as ISO images can be created instead of burning discs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

K3B will do this. Personally, I never use Brasero, and always use K3B, even when I'm using Gnome. It has many more features than Brasero. Anywho, to install, just search the Ubuntu Software Center for K3B, or:

```
sudo apt-get install k3b
```

To make sure it keeps the timestamps, after you create the CD/ISO and click Burn, then Click the Filesystem tab, then the Custom button.

[image: k3b burn dialog screenshot]

Then check the "Preserve file permissions (backup)" checkbox.

[image: k3b burn dialog screenshot]

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have to archive said files inside a `.tar` file so that all the file data is kept intact and then burn the `.tar` file to a CD/DVD. You will be able to open the `.tar` file using the archive manager and use files as normal.